# No query results for model [App\Project] in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need pass and save project_id in to the task table. regarding with tasks to each projects. i have two models like Project and Task
project Model

```
namespace App;
use Auth;
use App\Task;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['project_name','project_notes','project_status','color','group'];
    //

    public function tasks(){
         return $this->hasMany('App\Task');
}
```

Task model

```
class Task extends Model
{
     protected $fillable = ['task_name', 'body', 'assign','priority','duedate','project_id'];



      public function scopeProject($query, $id)
    {
        return $query->where('project_id', $id);
    }


     public function projects()
     {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');
     }
```

My TaskController

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $task = new Task;
    $task->task_name   = $request->input('name');
    $task->body = $request->input('body');
    $task->assign = $request->input('status');
    $task->priority = $request->input('status');

    $project = Project::findOrFail($request->get('project_id'));


    $project->tasks()->save($task);
}
```

now I have occurred this error massage

```
No query results for model [App\Project]
```

how can fix this problem?

Comment: It cannot find any project record in database. do you have any records in db with given id?

Comment: In which line does the error happen?

Comment: `Project::findOrFail(..)` will fail if no project with the given id is found in the DB.